# Replacing Carriage Returns "ch13?" in Datagridview with <br> using ONLY javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a way to replace a carriage return with the html break. I think it is cr13? Not entirely sure. I am new to programming. I have a content page. So i am setting the javascript in the content area. I have many other javascripts in the page. One hides and shows columns. So i have a way to find the columns. But i think i need to find the cells? It is only one column where this is needed. I am using asp.net, with vb.net, importing a sql server 2008 db. Unfortunatly this must be done in just javascript to avoid page reloads on the click of a button.

Thanks.

```
    function showComments() {
        Begincol_num = 8
        Endcol_num = 9
        Commentcol_num = 7
        rows = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

            rows[i].cells[Begincol_num].style.display = "none";
            rows[i].cells[Endcol_num].style.display = "none";
            rows[i].cells[Commentcol_num].style.display = "";

        }
    }
```

The idea is put the js to replace the cr with br within this function(if possible). I am at a loss as to where to start to call the replace in the comment cells. There are 30 comment cells, in the comment column at the moment and will only grow as it goes. This function is called on the click of a button that is not meant to return to the server, which is what i meant by only js.

I am trying to be as clear as possible. I know vb and asp but js makes no sense to me.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Comment: What does "ONLY javascript" have to do with it? Replacing carriage returns with HTML markup is [*orthogonal*](http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/orthogonal) to how/when the page refreshes. (I take it there is already a DGV on the page? I would look at the *current* databinding/datasource and fix how that applies the values...)

Comment: I agree with the others, you seem to have some unrelated assumptions.  If you can post some code and explain your intentions, it will help.  Good questions = good answers.  [There is some help here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, new lines are represented by "\n", the new line character. If you want to replace a new line with a `<br />`, then use the string replace function

```
var stringWithBR = stringVarName.replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Or to replace _all_ new line characters and not just the first one: `.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your comments are contained directly inside the cells with no other tags in between, you could do this:

```
// ...
 for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].cells[Begincol_num].style.display = "none";
  rows[i].cells[Endcol_num].style.display = "none";
  var commentCell = rows[i].cells[Commentcol_num];
  commentCell.style.display = "";
  commentCell.innerHTML = commentCell.innerHTML.replace("/\n/g", "<br />");
 }
// ...
```

But it is not a clean solution to do such a thing on showing the comments at all. You should do it either directly on the server or else on load. Otherwise, if you show and hide the comments more than once, you will do some unnecessary work which may not be a performance- but definitely a design problem.

After all problems could occur if there are line breaks inside HTML tags inside a comment. You can prevent that by using [innerText](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/all.htm#inner_text) and [textContent](http://blog.coderlab.us/2005/09/22/using-the-innertext-property-with-firefox/) but that would erase any tags. Better solutions are complicated.